# All permutations of random value within list of values using python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to reach the following result using python (thought about itertools), I have 4 rows that each can get one the values = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], since we have 3 options and 4 rows, then number of possibilities will be 3^4 = 81

For example:

```
    col1  col2  col3 ....... col81  
1    v1    v1    v_  
2    v2    v3
3    v1    v2
4    v3    v1
```

how can I achieve it, in such a way that I cover all the possibilities?

Comment: There are only 3! = 6 ways to permute that list. Are you looking to take the Cartesian product instead?

Comment: Not really, I need one value only from the list (of 3 values) each time, 4 times... that's gives 3^4 possibilities and each column per my understanding will represent one possibility, I'll edit my table example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the "product" not the "permutation". Try this:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

v = [1, 2, 3]

pprint(list(itertools.product(v, repeat=4)))
```

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 1, 3),
 (1, 1, 2, 1),
 (1, 1, 2, 2),
...
 (3, 3, 2, 3),
 (3, 3, 3, 1),
 (3, 3, 3, 2),
 (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```

If you need the transpose of that, you can do this:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

v = [1, 2, 3]

product = list(itertools.product(v, repeat=4))
transpose = list(map(list, zip(*product)))
pprint(transpose)
```

Comment: Thanks. did something similar: df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(product).T, index= keys, columns= coln, dtype= np.object) to get the table that I was targeting

Comment: @zbeedatm glad to have helped :)